# Filter a select where results of expression meet criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

Rarely interact with db's and no formal training.  I'm trying to select the `result.id` that meet a calculated criteria after an `INNER JOIN`.

`results` table:

```
|  id  |  infos_id  |  ...
 00001    99999
 00002    99998
 ...
```

`infos` table:

```
|  info_id  |  counts_id  |  ...
    99999      12345
    99998      12346
    ...
```

`counts` table:

```
|  count_id  |  numerator  |  denom  |  ...
   12345          100         1000
   12346          150         1000
   ...
```

When I perform this query:

```
SELECT r.id AS result_id, 
c.count_id AS count_id,
c.numerator/CAST(c.denom AS numeric) * 100 AS freq 
FROM results r INNER JOIN infos i ON r.infos_id = i.info_id 
INNER JOIN counts c ON i.counts_id = c.count_id 
WHERE r.id = 00001;
```

I get these results:

```
 result_id | count_id |          freq          
----------+-----------+------------------------
 00001     |   12345  | 10.0
```

I'd like do this for all `N` results and filter by `freq`, when I try substituting the `WHERE` clause with this:

```
WHERE freq < 12.0;
```

I get this:

```
ERROR:  column "freq" does not exist
```

Is there a simple change I can make to have my query return only the `results.id` that are < some given `freq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the calculation in the `WHERE` statement instead of the alias of `freq`. Something like below should work:

```
SELECT r.id AS result_id, 
c.count_id AS count_id,
c.numerator/CAST(c.denom AS numeric) * 100 AS freq 
FROM results r 
INNER JOIN infos i 
    ON r.infos_id = i.info_id 
INNER JOIN counts c 
    ON i.counts_id = c.count_id 
WHERE c.numerator/CAST(c.denom AS numeric) * 100 < 12
```

Comment: So the key is not using an alias in the WHERE.  That did it, thanks!